# What is the term for that style device when a soundtrack turns out to be heard within the reality of the film?

Tags: film-techniques, soundtrack

I believe the initial scene of Eyes Wide Shut is an example for this. I am sure I've heard a fancy term for the use of a piece of soundtrack that turns out to be heard within the film itself. How is that called?

Comment: Do you mean diegetic sound\music? http://filmsound.org/terminology/diegetic.htm

Comment: That scene goes from non-diegetic to diegetic. Is there a sound editing term for that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [*diegetic music*](http://filmsound.org/terminology/diegetic.htm), or more colloquially [Source Music](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SourceMusic). Switching back and forth in a single scene is called a "diegetic switch", or "cross-over diegetic music".

TVTropes has other terms for various incarnations of this, some of which are probably "official" and others probably invented by the site's community, e.g.:

- 'Interscene diegetic': when the same song plays continuously, in-universe, across multiple scenes.
- "Left the Background Music On": a specific diegetic switch where the music starts out as background music, until one of the characters "notices" it and it becomes diegetic.
- "Theme Tune Cameo": (the other answer that gave this seems to have vanished) a specific form of diegetic music where it's the main title theme that later appears in-scene somewhere.

Comment: This fits some Movies, but falls before the scope of others: *The Long Goodbye*, for one, uses it's 'Theme song' both diegetically and non.

Answer (score 0):

Any music heard as part of the 'reality' of the film's universe is called Source Music. I've never heard anyone say diegetic music on a production.

Comment: that's not surprising, as it's the "scientific" term that's probably only used for artistic or analytical discussions, but it is the right term: http://filmsound.org/terminology/diegetic.htm